# ¿Cómo alinear horizontalmente tres divs?

Tags: html

Tengo este codigo y me debería alinear los divs en una línea pero no lo hace...

El content es el bloque que engloba todos y luego los tres divs form1 try y form2.

Alguien me sabria decir que falla.

```css
.content{
        margin-left:100px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family:Verdana;
 border: 2px solid #CCC;
 width: 75%;
 height: 25%;
 background-color:#FAFAFA;
}
/* LOS tres FORMULARIOS*/
.form1{
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid #CCC;
 height: 200px;
 width: 35%;
 float:left;
}
.try {
        
     margin-left:280px;
     width: 15%;
     height: 200px;
     border: 2px solid #CCC;
}
.form2{
        float:right;
 border: 2px solid #CCC;
 height: 200px;
 width: 35%;
 margin-left:415px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div class= "tituloCliente">
            <p>Datos del Cliente</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form1">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cliente:</td>
                        <td><label for="codigoClient">00005120</label></td> 
                        <td><label for="nomClient"></label></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Persona de contacto:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="customerContact"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email comercial:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Telefono:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="telf"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>FAX:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fax"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Direccion principal:</td>
                        <td><label for="direcc"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Comentarios:</td>
                        <td><label for="coments"></label></td>

                    </tr>
                 
                </table>

            </form> 
        </div>
        <div class="try">
           <button>Search</button>
            </div>
        <div class="form2">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td>NIF:</td>
                        <th><label for="nif"></label></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tipo de Pago:</td>
                        <td><label for="payType"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condiciones de pago:</td>
                        <td><label for="condOfPay"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tarifa:</td>
                        <td><label for="tarifa"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form> 

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Has intentado usar las clases de las columnas de bootstrap, son muy comodas y sencillas de usar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo ajustando los width de cada form con sus márgenes pero en mi caso he optado por usar el `display: flex` (puedes informarte de como funciona el flexbox en navegadores, es una forma de usar el grid muy simple).

De todas maneras aqui te dejo un codepen para que lo pruebes y  entiendas mejor el funcionamiento https://codepen.io/DSGDSR/pen/GQMzoQ

Aquí te dejo el código con la explicación:

En el html he incluido los forms en un div con clase .forms para aplicarle el flexbox sin que le afecte al titulo (Datos de cliente)

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="tituloCliente">
        <p>Datos del Cliente</p>
    </div>

    <!-- He incluido los forms en un div con clase .forms para aplicarle el flexbox sin que le afecte al titulo (Datos de cliente) -->
    <div class="forms">
        <div class="form1">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cliente:</td>
                        <td><label for="codigoClient">00005120</label></td>
                        <td><label for="nomClient"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Persona de contacto:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="customerContact"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email comercial:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Telefono:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="telf"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>FAX:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fax"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Direccion principal:</td>
                        <td><label for="direcc"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Comentarios:</td>
                        <td><label for="coments"></label></td>

                    </tr>

                </table>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="try">
            <button>Search</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form2">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>NIF:</td>
                        <th><label for="nif"></label></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tipo de Pago:</td>
                        <td><label for="payType"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Condiciones de pago:</td>
                        <td><label for="condOfPay"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tarifa:</td>
                        <td><label for="tarifa"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y en el css el funcionamiento del grid usando flexbox. ajustando los respectivos width de cada formulario se ajustara el margen tambien abajo explico el `justify-content: space-around`

```
.content {
    margin-left: 100px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 75%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
.forms {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
/* LOS tres FORMULARIOS*/
.form1 {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    height: 200px;
    width: 40%;
}
.try {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 20%;
}
.form2 {
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    height: 200px;
    width: 35%;
}
```

Funcionamiento del `justify-content: space-around` (requiere el `display: flex`)
Los items flex se alinean uniformemente de tal manera que el espacio entre dos items adyacentes es el mismo. El espacio vacío anterior al primer item y posterior al último item equivale a la mitad del espacio entre dos items adyacentes.

Aún así si todavía estas aprendiendo te recomendaría usar el sistema de grid de [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) o frameworks como [FlexboxGrid](http://flexboxgrid.com/)

Comment: Buen aporte, y muy completo los ejemplos.

Answer (score 1):

Hice un par de cambios en el css, los 3 contenedores deben ser flotantes a la izquierda y ajustar el ancho de cada uno

El css actualizado

```
    .content{
    /*margin-left: 100px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 75%;
    /* height: 25%; */
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
/* LOS tres FORMULARIOS*/
.form1{
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 200px;
    width: 40%;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    float: left;
}
.try {
    float: left;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    width: 19.2%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.form2{
    /* display: inline-block; */
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 200px;
    width: 40%;
    /* margin-left: 415px; */

}
```

El [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kqp1a8pt/5/) funcionando

De todas maneras, te recomiendo usar bootstrap en cualquiera de sus versiones para ayudarte a manejar el tema de las columnas mucho mas facil

Saludos